# Is reading/writing in an array more efficient than reading/writing a char/byte one by one?

Tags: java, optimization, inputstream, outputstream

```
try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("input.txt")) {

    int c;
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1)
        System.out.print((char)c);

} catch (Exception ignored) { }
```

In this code, I read a char by char. Is it more efficient in someway to read a into an array of chars at once? In other words, is there any kind of optimization that happens when reading in arrays?

For example in this code, I have an array of `char` called `arr` and I read into it until there is noting left to read. Is it more efficient?

```
    try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("input.txt")) {

        int size;
        char[] arr = new char[100];
        while ((size = reader.read(arr)) != -1)
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                System.out.print(arr[i]);

    } catch (Exception ignored) { }
```

The question applies for both reading/writing both chars/bytes.

Comment: You are reading from a file system, so yes; using "chunks" (aka a buffer) will lead to more efficient reads. Mainly because reading blocks. And reading sequential data does not require seeking twice.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If I use `BufferedWriter`, would reading in chunks be faster?

Comment: I assume you mean a `BufferedReader`, and that reads the "chunks" for you. We call it a buffer. Not a chunk.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks. I'm gonna update the question. I meant If I have a buffered reader, is it faster to read into an array or to read char by char?

Comment: Probably not, since the buffered reader internally keeps an array... that is the buffer and that is what it internally fills. You are emptying the buffer one character at a time. Not filling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the reader. The answer can be yes, though. Whatever Reader or InputStream is the actual 'raw' driver (the one that isn't just wrapping another reader or inputstream, but the one that is actually talking to the OS to get the data) - it may well implement the single-character `read()` method by asking the OS to read a single character.

In the end, you have a disk, and disks return data in blocks. So if you ask for 1 byte, you have 2 options as a computer:

1. Ask the disk for the block that contains the byte that is to be read. Store the block in memory someplace for a while. Return one byte; for the next few moments, if more requests for bytes come in from the same block, return from the stored data in memory and don't bother asking the disk at all. NOTE: This requires memory! Who allocates it? How much memory is okay? Tricky questions. OSes tend to give low level tools and don't like just picking values for any of these questions.
2. Ask the disk for the block that contains the byte that is to be read. Find the 1 byte needed from within this block. Ignore the rest of the data, return just that one byte. If in a few moments another byte from that block is asked for... ask the disk, again, for the whole block, and repeat this routine.

Which of the two models you get depends on many factors: For example: What kind of disk is it, what OS do you have, what underlying java reader are you using. But it is plausible you end up in this second mode and that is, as you can probably tell, usually incredibly slow, because you end up reading the same block 4000+ times instead of only once.

So, how to fix this? Well, java doesn't really know what the OS is doing either, so the safest bet is to let *java* do the caching. Then you have no dependencies on whatever the OS is doing.

You could write it yourself, so instead of:

```
for (int i = in.read(); i != -1; i = in.read()) {
    processOneChar((char) i);
}
```

you could do:

```
char[] buffer = new char[4096];
while (true) {
    int r = in.read(buffer);
    if (r == -1) break;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) processOneChar(buffer[i]);
}
```

more code, but now the second scenario (the same block is read off the disk a ton of times) can no longer occur; you have given the OS the freedom to return to you up to 4096 chars worth of data.

Or, use a java builtin: BufferedX:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
for (int i = br.read(); i != -1; i = br.read()) {
    processOneChar((char) i);
}
```

The implementation of `BufferedReader` guarantees that java will take care of making some reasonably sized buffer to avoid rereads of the same block off of disk.

NB: Note that the FileReader constructor you are using should not be used. It uses platform default encoding (anytime you convert bytes to characters, encoding is involved), and platform default is a recipe for untestable bugs, which are very bad. Use `new FileReader(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead, or better yet, use the new API:

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:/file.txt");
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(p)) {
    for (int i = br.read(); i != -1; i = br.read()) {
        processOneChar((char) i);
    }
}
```

Note that this:

1. Defaults to UTF-8, because the Files API defaults to UTF-8 unlike most places in the VM.
2. Makes a bufferedreader immediately, no need to make it yourself.
3. Properly manages the resource (ensures it is closed regardless of how this code exits, be it normally or be exception), by using an ARM block.
4. Because a BufferedX is involved, no risk of the 'read the same block a lot' performance hole.

NB: The same logic applies when writing; disks such as SSDs can only write a whole block at a time. Now it's not just slow as molasses to write, you're also ruining your disk, as they get a limited number of writes.

Comment: Can you provide a source where I can know more about "the name API"?

Comment: Aw nuts, that was an unfortunate typo! I meant to type 'the new API'. I'm talking about this one: https://www.baeldung.com/java-nio-2-file-api - typo corrected in the answer.